# How to show a graph is homeomorphic to a subset of a product space?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

$X, Y$ are topological spaces and $X \times Y$ is given the product topology.
The subspace $ G \subseteq X \times Y$ is defined as: $ G =$ { $(x,y) \in X \times Y | y = f(x)$ }.
How can one show that if the map $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, then $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

Also; I have a hard time visualising what is happening. If anyone has any advise on that or knows of any good videos it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $G$ is the graph of $f$. For example, the "parabola" you represent in the $xy$-plane is $G$ for $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$. Notice that the map $\rho:G\rightarrow X$ mapping $(x,f(x))$ to $x$ is continuous (since it's the composition $$G\hookrightarrow X\times Y\xrightarrow{\pi}X$$ and if $f$ is continuous, then $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is the inverse of $\rho$ and continuous

Comment: I have changed "subgroup" into "graph" in your title.

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro , that makes it a lot easier to visualize.

Comment: @Rory, notice that the projection $G\rightarrow X$ is always continuous, 1-1 and onto. It is an homeomorphism if and only if $f$ in continuous

Answer (score 2):

$G$ is just the graph of $f$, and if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, the map $F: X \to X \times Y; F(x)=(x, f(x))$ is too, as $\pi_X \circ F = 1_X$ and $\pi_Y \circ F = f$ are both continuous by assumption and $G = F[X]$, so $F$ is a bijective continuous map from $X$ onto $G$, and it has a continuous inverse $\pi_X\restriction_G$, so $F$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not too familiar with topology and the different kinds of notations just yet. I was wondering what $\pi_X\restriction_G$, means?

Comment: @Rory the restriction of the projection map (onto $X$) to the set $G$.

Comment: Ahh.. makes sense.